# Diophantine equation no integer solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

Show that the following equation has no integer solutions:

$x^3+3x^2+2x=z^3-4z+4.$

No idea where to start because it has no $y$ functions.

Also I need to find the integer solutions to 
$y^2+x^2=9-z^2$.

Comment: For your second equation note that $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, so $-3\le x,y,z\le 3$.

Comment: For the second question, you should really make a second post. However, there are only a few possibilities for $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ since $|x|,|y|,|z|\le3$.

Comment: If you change all the $z$s to $y$ in the first equation then you have $y$ functions but no $z$ functions. Is that better?

Comment: If i change z to y, factorise both side to x(x+1)(x+2)-y(y-2)(y+2)=z^2 , where z=2. Where do i go from there, or am i going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the equation mod $3$ using [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

**More hints:**
$$
\begin{align}
x^3&\equiv x&\pmod3\\
3x^2&\equiv0&\pmod3\\
2x&\equiv-x&\pmod3\\
\\
z^3&\equiv z&\pmod3\\
4z&\equiv z&\pmod3\\
4&\equiv1&\pmod3
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^3+3x^2+2x=x(x+1)(x+2)$ divizible by $3$. Then applying mod 3 we get:
$0=1$ because of $a^p = a \mod p$ when $p$ prime.

Comment: pretty similar to my hint

Comment: @robjohn Yes, Fermat LT is the key here